# Можно сказать "человек с грозным провидением"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли будет сказать (есть ли в этом ошибка) *человек с грозным провидением*?

Имеется в виду человек с тяжелой судьбой.

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что нельзя. Начните с [определения этого слова](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), посмотрите [примеры употребления](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Провидение не есть что-то, чем может в той или иной мере обладать человек (как, например, судьбой).

Более того, согласно как определению, так и примерам, провидение обычно несёт в себе некий позитивный смысл, что опять же не вяжется с Вашей задумкой.